# Can't run a ruby hello world application in Aptana

Tags: ruby, aptana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't run a ruby hello world application in Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889711/cant-run-a-ruby-hello-world-application-in-aptana)

I've just installed the latest version of Aptana.

I've then tried to create a project, residing in `C:\Users\User\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\abc` that only contains a single `main.rb` file with the following contents:

```
puts "hello world"
```

When trying to run it, it spits out the following message:

> c:\Ruby192\bin\rubyw.EXE: No such file or directory --
>   User/AppData/Local/Aptana (LoadError)

The `c:\Ruby192\bin\rubyw.EXE` file name seems correct. When looking in the configuration options, the full filename of the file to be run also seems correct.

I've tried to copy the `main.rb` to `C:\`, as it looked at first glance as the problem could be related with white spaces, but even then the error remains the same!

I wonder what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will fix it, but [Max gave the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889711/cant-run-a-ruby-hello-world-application-in-aptana/6892125#6892125) to [a similar problem I had asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6889711/539490):

> This has been fixed in 3.0.4 which is now under QA and will be public
>   early this week. You have a choice of either wait or switch to Beta
>   builds following instructions at
>   http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+Update+Type
>
> Cheers, Max

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `C:\Ruby192\bin` to your PATH environment variable. See how that works.