# Can't run a ruby hello world application in Aptana

Tags: ruby, aptana

I have the same problem as [asked by another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886525) but it gives a different error message:

> "C:\Ruby192\bin\rubyw.EXE: No such file or directory -- SDK-3.7
>   (LoadError)"

Does any one have a fix?  I see there's [a similar problem on Aptana's support page](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3184-aptana-studio-3-not-able-to-run-ruby-debugger-after-update), but again, the error message is slightly different:

> C:\Ruby\Ruby192\bin\rubyw.EXE: No such file or directory -- Studio
>   (LoadError)

I can excecute Ruby programs normally on my computer so it's not a question of adding the correct environment variable to my path.... I guess this is an Aptana problem.  Should I file a support ticket with them?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in 3.0.4 which is now under QA and will be public early this week.
You have a choice of either wait or switch to Beta builds following instructions at http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+Update+Type

Cheers,
Max