# Can't run ruby in aptana studio 3.4.2

Tags: ruby, aptana

As the problem described in 
[Can't run a ruby hello world application in Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886525/cant-run-a-ruby-hello-world-application-in-aptana).

The answer says it is fixed in 3.0.4. But I still got the same error c:\ruby\bin\rubyw.EXE: Permission denied -- C:/ruby/bin (LoadError).

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason of this problem is cause of your computer security level.
So you need to decrease your security level

OR

①Change your Ruby installed file (eg. Ruby193 folder) to D Drive or other operating system not installed place.

②and copy your URL until bin folder of Ruby change place .
eg.D:\Ruby193\bin

③
and change and paste　the URL that you copied to your computer Path of system variables which having at environment variable setting .

Comment: I have changed the ruby file to E Drive, but still come about the same error.

Comment: After changing the ruby file, Do you also update ruby installed path in the environment variable of your computer?

Comment: Yes. Now the error message is "e:\ruby\bin\rubyw.EXE: Permission denied -- e:/ruby/bin (LoadError)".